# matplotlib scatterplot: adding 4th dimension by the marker shape

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to add a fourth dimension to the scatter plot by defining the ellipticity of the markers depending on a variable. Is that possible somehow ?

EDIT:

I would like to avoid a 3D-plot. In my opinion these plots are usually not very informative.

Comment: What are the first three dimensions? x, y and color or x, y, z? or x,y, size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place `Ellipse` patches directly onto your axes, as demonstrated in [this matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ellipse_demo.html). To adapt it to use eccentricity as your "third dimension") keeping the marker area constant:

```
from pylab import figure, show, rand
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 25

# ellipse centers
xy = np.random.rand(N, 2)*10
# ellipse eccentrities
eccs = np.random.rand(N) * 0.8 + 0.1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

A = 0.1
for pos, e in zip(xy, eccs):
    # semi-minor, semi-major axes, b and a:
    b = np.sqrt(A/np.pi  * np.sqrt(1-e**2))
    a = A / np.pi / b
    ellipse = Ellipse(xy=pos, width=2*a, height=2*b)
    ax.add_artist(ellipse)

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

show()
```

[image]

Of course, you need to scale your marker area to your x-, y- values in this case.

Comment: Yep, currently I am playing around with this Idea. works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colorbar` as the 4th dimension to your 3D plot. One example is as shown below:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cmx
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

def scatter3d(x,y,z, cs, colorsMap='jet'):
    cm = plt.get_cmap(colorsMap)
    cNorm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(cs), vmax=max(cs))
    scalarMap = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm, cmap=cm)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=scalarMap.to_rgba(cs))
    scalarMap.set_array(cs)
    fig.colorbar(scalarMap,label='Test')
    plt.show()

x = np.random.uniform(0,1,50)
y = np.random.uniform(0,1,50)
z = np.random.uniform(0,1,50)
```

so `scatter3D(x,y,z,x+y)` produces:

with `x+y` being the 4th dimension shown in color. You can add your calculated ellipticity depending on your specific variable instead of `x+y` to get what you want.

[image]

Comment: useful answer, but I would like to avoid 3D plots

Answer (score 1):

To change the ellipticity of the markers you will have to create them manually as such a feature is not implemented yet. However, I believe you can show 4 dimensions with a 2D scatter plot by using color and size as additional dimensions. You will have to take care of the scaling from data to marker size yourself. I added a simple function to handle that in the example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(60,4)

def scale_size(data, data_min=None, data_max=None, size_min=10, size_max=60):

    # if the data limits are set to None we will just infer them from the data
    if data_min is None:
        data_min = data.min()
    if data_max is None:
        data_max = data.max()

    size_range = size_max - size_min
    data_range = data_max - data_min

    return ((data - data_min) *  size_range / data_range) + size_min


plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=data[:,2], s=scale_size(data[:,3]))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]